# VBA: userform multipage template

Tags: vba, userform, multipage

I'm making a Userform that would allow the user to changes the bounds on several charts at once. I figured out how everything should look on the first multipage, and now I'm wondering if there's any way I could add 11 pages at once to look just like the first page. My userform appears below.

[image: Userform]

I am still in the design phase for this. If there's a way to do this in the design that would be great. If there's a way to do in the Initialize sub that would also be great.

Comment: If you do a full select from one, and copy paste to another it will be close. Not perfect though.

Comment: May be you should consider **TabStrip** instead of MultiPage if all look similar, less codes in initial and maintaining too. Advise you to add **SpinButton**s next to these textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your intended usage, you should be using a **TabStrip** instead of **MultiPage** being most controls within are the same layout (same amount of controls). MultiPage is intended for categorizing data with different controls on each page.

Consider this simple userform to demostrate the benefit of using TabStrip here:

[image: UserForm Design]

The left side square is a Picture holder I have not put codes for.

With below code to handle tab changes, certain elements in the userform will change when a different Tab is clicked.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()
    Dim TabX As String
    With Me.TabStrip1
        TabX = .Tabs(.Value).Caption
        Debug.Print "ActiveTab:", TabX
    End With
    Me.Frame1.Caption = "Maximum Bounds (" & TabX & ")"
    Me.Frame2.Caption = "Minimum Bounds (" & TabX & ")"
    Me.TextBox1.Value = "TextBox2 for " & TabX ' Forgot to change this Value to TextBox1 before the screenshot...
    Me.TextBox2.Value = "TextBox2 for " & TabX
End Sub
```

1. Upon launching the userform (without setting `UserForm_Initialize`):
   [image: FirstLaunch]
2. Tab2 clicked:
   [image: Tab2Click]
3. Tab1 clicked:
   [image: Tab2Click]

Comment: Thank you! This is my first foray into userforms and I'm mostly teaching myself. Your answer is very helpful!